# put the whole list in one dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a dictionary:

```
dict = {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar': [5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

and I use the below command to create the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')
```

but the output is like:

```
df:
           0  1  2  3
     foo   1  2  3  4
     bar   4  5  6  7
```

but I expect the output to be like below with only one column:

```
df:
           'column_name'
     foo    [1, 2, 3, 4]
     bar    [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Why do you want this? It pretty much defeats the point of Pandas

Comment: Never name your dictionary `dict`. :(

Comment: Use `pd.Series(dct).to_frame('column_name')`, but you really don't want to do this.

Comment: because in reality the list is long and I have more columns. All those belong to one specific column and later I want to only read this column.

Comment: @AmirHosseinF I think it would be easier to help if you explained the next step.

Comment: One column means it has a single element per row. Just wrap each row in a list.

Comment: @IvanDePazCenteno You mean like: `df = pd.DataFrame([dictionary], index=['column_name']).T`, because that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a dictionary containing "list-like" values. When passed to the DataFrame *constructor*, `pandas` interprets the keys of the dictionaries as Series labels, and the values in each list as new row values per Series.

When you use the `from_dict` class method, you are given the option of orientation, which allows you to specify whether or not the keys of the dictionary represent row or column labels, but the "list-like" values of the dictionary will still be interpreted either as new columns or new rows.

Using both of these methods also requires that the lengths of the values are uniform.

---

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index')
```

```
     0  1  2  3
foo  1  2  3  4
bar  5  6  7  8
```

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='columns')
```

```
   foo  bar
0    1    5
1    2    6
2    3    7
3    4    8
```

---

Instead, you are interested in the 1-Dimensional `pd.Series`, which will take a dictionary and use each key as a row label, and each value as a row value.

```
pd.Series(dct)
```

```
foo    [1, 2, 3, 4]
bar    [5, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

Per my comment above, if you are interested in a DataFrame, you can use `to_frame`, which will maintain the values stored in the `Series`.

```
pd.Series(dct).to_frame('column_name')
```

```
      column_name
foo  [1, 2, 3, 4]
bar  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in python3.6+ you can lean on the ordered nature of dictionaries to create a different dictionary of just `column_name` being the key:

```py
d = {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'bar': [5, 6, 7, 8]}

df = pd.DataFrame([{'column_name': v} for v in d.values()], index=d.keys())

df
      column_name
foo  [1, 2, 3, 4]
bar  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Otherwise, I would definitely default to @user3483203's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame({'col_name': pd.Series(dict)})
```

Result:

```
         col_name
foo  [1, 2, 3, 4]
bar  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the dict to create series and convert to dataframe:

```
dct = {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4],
       'bar': [5, 6, 7, 8]}

pd.Series(dct).to_frame('column_name')

Out[937]:
      column_name
bar  [5, 6, 7, 8]
foo  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Note**: please don't use `dict` as the variable name. It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
frame=pd.Series(dict).rename('column_name')
```